# How to retrieve parent objects without children

Tags: c#, linq

I have parent class Person and child class Employee which is also parent class for Manager

```
class Person
{
    private int _personID;
    private string _fullName;
    ....
    ....
}

class Employee : Person
{
    private int _salary;
    ....
    ....
}

class Manager : Employee
{
    private Project _project;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now, I need to get Employees without managers. I tried:

```
var employees = from Employee e in db
                select e;
```

but then I noticed that I have managers inside my collection because of inheritance. So I thought it could be something like this:

```
var employees = from Employee e in db
                from Manager m in db
                where e.PersonID != m.PersonID
                select e;
```

But now I donэt have managers inside collection but I have twice the same information in my collection because of inheritance. I need only parents without children.

I am using Db4o object database and I am not much familiar with LINQ.

**Update:**

```
EmbeddedObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(PATH_TO_DATABASE);
```

I figured out how to do this, but you have to query twice so this is not a best solution.

```
var employees = from Employee e in db
                select e;

var managers = from Manager m in db
               select m;

var result = employees.Except(managers);
```

Comment: what does 'db' variable contains? what is the type of it?

Comment: I guess your `Employee` class could have a field called `ManagerID` which would link to `_personID` from `Manager`. Then you could just filter those employees with null `ManagerID` values.

Comment: Are you going to have people in your application that are not employees?  If not, then you don't need the Person class, you can put those properties into Employee.

Comment: @shree.pat18
I will try this later, but I was hoping for 'more' LINQ solution.

Comment: @Darren Young
Yes, I have people that are not employees.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with db4o nor the db4o Linq implementation, but with standard Linq this should work:

```
var employees = db.AsQueryable<Employee>().Where(e => !(e is Manager));
```

Comment: I got: System.InvalidOperationException - Stack Empty

Comment: @H0ney - I changed the Linq to use `IQueryable<>` as suggested [here](http://community.versant.com/Blogs/Db4o/tabid/197/entryid/147/Default.aspx)

Comment: Still the same error. And if you want some documentation for Db4o use  [THIS](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/)

Comment: I guess LINQ for db4o doesn't support those expressions. Do you have a navigation property in `Employee` to its `Manager` collection, something like `e.Managers`?